# NDK unable to find my module in the NDK_MODULE_PATH - android-ndk-profiler

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, profiling, profiler

I am trying to use android-ndk-profiler - https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler

As described in the usage document https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler/blob/master/docs/Usage.md

I unzipped the zip file to $HOME/Documents/Dev

My Android.mk looks like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkbasics
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkbasics.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

# compile with profiling
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -pg
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android-ndk-profiler

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# at the end of Android.mk
$(call import-module,android-ndk-profiler)
```

When trying to build using the command

```
ndk-build NDK_MODULE_PATH=$HOME/Documents/Dev/
```

I get the error

```
Android NDK: /Users/hanantha/Documents/Dev/projects/workspaceWeeklyPreso/NdkProfileMethods/jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'android-ndk-profiler' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
/Users/hanantha/Documents/Dev/projects/workspaceWeeklyPreso/NdkProfileMethods/jni/Android.mk:16: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

Additional points

- I have tried setting NDK_MODULE_PATH in my bash_profile
- ndk version r10d
- Ran the make file in the unzipped folder android-ndk-profiler

It is strange that ndk says the directories that it has searched is empty. What could be going wrong?

Comment: No I did not, I ended up compiling the android-ndk-profiler source along with my app that I was profiling with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done almost correct process need to change at one place as follow

```
# at the end of Android.mk
$(call import-module,android-ndk-profiler/jni)
```

Adding `jni` in import-module will solve your problem because it's working for me.